Find two furthest points in a point set in linear time (2-approximation algorithm)
Given a set of n points, find two points which is furthest from each other. We need to use 2-approximation algorithm which means actually, we do not need to accurately find these two points, we just need to find a set of points that the distance between them is at least half of the furthest distance, the algorithm should run in linear time.
I have tried WSPD (well separated pair decomposition), but the construction of WSPD itself takes O(n*logn) time. So it's not a valid solution.

Hi! A few questions: (1) What data structure holds the point set? Is it just a structure-less list of points? (2) Are the points in 2d, 3d, or larger-dimension space?

Related: A simple approximation algorithm for the diameter of a set of points in an Euclidean plane, 2019, Jieying Hong, Zhipeng Wang, Wei Niu

Thank you for replying! They can be multi-dimensional and the requirement is O(d*n), d is dimension. And the point set is stored in list. I came up with an idea: We can first calculate the minimum enclosing disk using randomized incremental algorithm, and we just need to find two points such that their distance is greater than or equal to the radius of that disk. But I don't know how to find such pair of point.

Surprisingly, the answer to this question is quite simple:
Randomly select a point from A, find the furthest point B from A, return the distance, and done!

This might work, but extensively test it with data and check:

Remove all the duplicates.
Shift all your points to the +x, +y, +z, .... plane.
Find the distance of each point from the origin.
Find min distance and max distance.
Find indices of the two points in min and max distances.

Code
class FindPair(object):
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.P = points
        self.dists = [0 for i in range(len(self.P))]

    def _shifted(self):
        Pm = []
        for x, y, z in self.P:
            Pm += [(x + 10, y + 10, z + 10)]
        return Pm

    def _eucl(self, x, y, z):
        return x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2

    def _search(self):
        Pm = self._shifted()
        for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(Pm):
            self.dists[i] = self._eucl(x, y, z)
        return self.dists

    def get_max_dist(self):
        self._search()
        min_dist, max_dist = min(self.dists), max(self.dists)
        imin, imax = self.dists.index(min_dist), self.dists.index(max_dist)
        return imin, imax

    def get_points(self):
        i, j = self.get_max_dist()
        return self.P[i], self.P[j]


base_points = ((0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 0), (-1, -1, 0), (0, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0),
               (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (0, -1, 1), (1, -1, 1),
               (0, 0, -1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 1, -1), (0, 1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 0, -1), (-1, -1, -1), (0, -1, -1), (1, -1, -1))

populations = []
for i in range(100, 105):
    for j in range(200, 205):
        for k in range(300, 305):
            for x, _, _ in base_points:
                for _, y, _ in base_points:
                    for _, _, z in base_points:
                        populations += [(x + i, y + j, z + k)]

finder = FindPair(populations)
print(finder.get_points())
print(len(populations))



Prints
((99, 199, 299), (105, 205, 305))
2460375



Note

For shifting, we can add a large number to x, y, z, ... of all points.

Complexity

Time complexity is O(N)
Space is O(N) in the above example, but you can make that constant.


Kites in the sky example
This approach is similar to having a set of "kites in the sky", all tighten up to one base in the ground. We want to find two kites with the max and min distance to the base in the ground.

Comparison with Brute Force O(N ^ 2)

Added based on the comments.

Code
import math

class FindPair(object):
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.P = points
        self.dists = [0 for i in range(len(self.P))]

    def _shifted(self):
        Pm = []
        for x, y, z in self.P:
            Pm += [(x + 1000, y + 1000, z + 1000)]
        return Pm

    def _eucl(self, x, y, z):
        return x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2

    def _search(self):
        Pm = self._shifted()
        for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(Pm):
            self.dists[i] = self._eucl(x, y, z)
        return self.dists

    def get_max_dist(self):
        self._search()
        min_dist, max_dist = min(self.dists), max(self.dists)
        imin, imax = self.dists.index(min_dist), self.dists.index(max_dist)
        return imin, imax

    def get_points(self):
        i, j = self.get_max_dist()
        return self.P[i], self.P[j]


class BruteForce(object):
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.P = points

    def _euclidean_distance(self, p1, p2):
        return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0]) ** 2 + (p1[1] - p2[1]) ** 2 + (p1[2] - p2[2]) ** 2)

    def get_max_dist(self):
        max_dist = 0
        max_pair = (None, None)
        for i in range(len(self.P)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(self.P)):
                dist = self._euclidean_distance(self.P[i], self.P[j])
                if dist > max_dist:
                    max_dist = dist
                    max_pair = (self.P[i], self.P[j])
        return max_pair


base_points = ((0, -3, 0), (1, 3, 0), (0, 3, 0), (-1, 3, 0), (0, 1, 0))

# populations = []
# for i in range(100, 105):
#     for j in range(200, 205):
#         for k in range(300, 305):
#             for x, _, _ in base_points:
#                 for _, y, _ in base_points:
#                     for _, _, z in base_points:
#                         populations += [(x + i, y + j, z + k)]

finder = FindPair(base_points)
print(finder.get_points())
brute_force = BruteForce(base_points)
print(brute_force.get_max_dist())
# print(len(populations))



Prints
((0, -3, 0), (1, 3, 0))
((0, -3, 0), (1, 3, 0))
Comments

@btilly in the comments seems to have a point. While I'm not still sure, because this approach is "too easy" for the problem introduced that requires approximation methods, (may be even an NP-complete).

Problems may arise when the points are too far from each other and in infinite dimensions, and shifting them may not be simple or a choice at all, or may overcomplicate the computations. If we have infinite dimensions, this is then an NP-complete problem.


For a 1000 dimensions, however, we may be able to modify the distance equation to x1 ^ 2 + x2 ^ 2 + x3 ^ 2 + ... + x1000 ^ 2.

If our x, y, z, ... numbers are too large we could normalize all the numbers to a range of small numbers and use double precision computations.

There are more to take into consideration.



I think this has almost all of the key ideas, but isn't quite right. What happens if the min distance and max distance are in the same direction as each other?

@btilly You may be right. I don't follow, however. Can you maybe make a set of points and see how the direction would contradict?

@btilly I have used moore neighborhood and added 24 directions in the base_points, initially?

For the original solution, [(0, -3, 0), (1, 3, 0), (0, 3, 0), (-1, 3, 0), (0, 1, 0)] is a counterexample. The problem is using the min point at all - that's not needed.

@btilly I'm getting these two points: ((0, -3, 0), (1, 3, 0)). Which two points should we get?

Huh, did I misread it? Apparently so. If so, what do you use for base points if you've got 1000 dimensions?

Seeing some of the ideas from @user24714692 made me see the simple answer.

Find the center c of the set of points. This has the property that for any point p1 in the points that is not on the center, there must be another point p2 "on the other side of the center", that is with (p1-c) ⋅ (p2-c) < 0.
Find p1, the farthest point from c. The farthest distance between two points cannot be more than 2x the distance of this point from the center.
Find p2, the farthest point from p1. Any point "on the other side of the center" from p2 must be farther than the center is. And so (p1, p2) is our answer.

Here is code for this.
# This is O(d) where d is the number of dimensions.
def norm2 (point):
    return sum((point[i] * point[i] for i in range(len(point))))

# This is O(n*d)   
def center (points):
    return tuple((
        sum(point[i] for point in points)/len(points)
            for i in range(len(points[0]))
            ))

# This is O(d)
def difference (point1, point2):
    return tuple((
        point1[i] - point2[i]
            for i in range(len(point1))
            ))

# This is O(n*d)    
def farthest_from_position(points, position):
    farthest_point = points[0]
    farthest_d2 = norm2(difference(farthest_point, position))
    for point in points:
        d2 = norm2(difference(point, position))
        if farthest_d2 < d2:
            farthest_d2 = d2
            farthest_point = point
    return farthest_point

# This is O(n*d)
# Returns a pair guaranteed to be at least half the maximum distance apart.
def far_pair(points):
    c = center(points)
    p1 = farthest_from_position(points, c)
    p2 = farthest_from_position(points, p1)
    return (p1, p2)

